# Unable to find tmux session but it shows up as a file?

Tags: ssh, tmux, session, byobu

Yesterday I had started a tmux session, but when I logged into the computer today, I cannot find it, i.e. `tmux ls` cannot find the session.

But when I run `top` I can see that the following tmux process is running

`tmux -u -2 -f /usr/share/byobu/profiles/tmuxrc -S longer_scrollback`

`longer_scrollback` is a name I had used when creating the session with `byobu`.

Also, weirdly  this shows up as a file in the directory listing in which the `byobu` session was started.

```
srw-rw---- 1 kg314 kg314    0 May  2 19:13 longer_scrollback=
```

with a trailing `=` after my session name.  Any idea how to re-attach to this session?